# How much time does it take for Firebase Crashlytics to report?

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Usually the time between crash and crash report in (Firebase)Crashlytics is almost instant, sometimes we are experiencing some lag and now no crash at all. Is there any guarantees of time or timeout for crash report? (similar like in Firebase Analytics) I was searching documentation, but I can't find it.

Why I'm asking? We have an app which is crashing, but no logs anywhere and I'm trying to figure out why the crash didn't appear in Crashlytics console.